# Introducing stream function with given velocity equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, potential, flow, navier-stokes

***Bit information about the problem***
We are dealing with the slide coating process - where basically a polymer is being put onto a slot, which is moving in the $x$-direction with velocity $v_0$. The volumetric flow rate $Q_w=Q/W$ where $Q$ is total volume-rate flow and W is the length in the $z$-direction. The polymer is solidifying the height is dropping from $h_0$ to $h_1$ for $x[0;L]$.

It is known:
- constant density and viscosity
- steady state
- newtonian fluid
- no gravity forces
- lubrication approximation

***Help required for***

We are given the following expression for velocity (in $x$ direction),

$$
v_x=(3v_0 - 6\frac{Q_w}{h})(\frac{y}{h})^2+(6*\frac{Q_w}{h}-4v_0)\frac{y}{h}+v_0
$$

We want to introduce the following stream functions
$$
v_x=-\frac{\delta \psi}{\delta y}
$$
$$
v_y=-\frac{\delta \psi}{\delta x}
$$

We are also given that $\psi(x,h(x))=0$. We wish to get an expression for $\psi(x,y)$ corresponding to $x[0;L]$ and $y[0;h]$.

***My approach***
So my approach to this problem was something like this.

I integrated the given $v_x$ equation to get the following

$$
\psi(x,h)=\int v_xdy + \phi(x)=v_x=(3v_0 - 6\frac{Q_w}{h})(\frac{y^3}{3h^2})+(6*\frac{Q_w}{h}-4v_0)\frac{y^2}{2h}+v_0 y + \phi(x)
$$

where $\phi(x)$ is a function.

Then I said that since we are not given an expression for $v_y$ therefore, I can differentiate the above w.r.t x, giving the following,

$$
\frac{\delta \psi}{\delta x} = 0+0+0+\frac{\phi(x)}{\delta x} = v_y
$$

From there I just assumed that $v_y = 0$.

I am pretty sure the last part is definitely wrong. But is there any other way of doing it?

My thoughts:
Should I determine an expression for $v_y$ from Navier-Stoke equation and only then use the stream function? Or I don't necessarily have to do that.

If additional information is required. Please write in the comment section, so I can provide it.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are describing.  Is the solidification taking place on the moving surface?  Does your analysis take into account the volumetric throughput rate of the solid?

Answer (score 0):

The Integration with respect to variable $y$ was correct. Now you have to Substitute $y=h(x)$ and use your given condition $\psi(x,y=h(x))=0$. From this you will know the x-dependent function $\phi(x)$. By differentiating this by $x$, you get $v_y$.

Remark: I know that the stream function $\psi$ is defined as

$v_x = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}, v_y = - \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$ (one positive sign and one negative sign). Is the Definition with both negative signs (both -) correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I made a mistake. Thank you for your help and for pointing it out :)

Comment: Oh sorry but in the problem, we are told that h=h(x), so its already in the expression. We don't have an actual expression for h(x).